# Meteor and OneSignal, how?

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor, push-notification, onesignal

I want to get OneSignal working with Meteor. OneSignal has several walkthroughs on their site, but none for Meteor. I tried following [the one for Cordova](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup), but that eventually resulted in, in Xcode, a "onesignal.h" not found error. Eventually, after trying to build a few times, this issue went away, but then I ran into "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

Using the plugin [astrocoders:one-signal](https://atmospherejs.com/astrocoders/one-signal) generates no results whatsoever.

I've had a back and forth with OneSignal support, but they were only able to direct me to the Cordova setup process.

How to get OneSignal to work with Meteor apps?

I'm open to using alternatives of OneSignal, too.

Comment: Have you tried the [npm package of onesignal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-onesignal) instead of the meteor package?

Comment: I have not. Also, I have yet to include an npm package in any of my Meteor projects. Thanks for the tip, @blueren I'll see what my mileage ends up being.